# MATLAB: How to read blob data from MySQL, and save as image?

Tags: mysql, image, matlab, blob

I have a bunch of images stored as blob data in database, now I would like to read(retrieve) these images from mysql using MATLAB, then do further image processing. However, the problem is: retrieved data is a N*1 unit8 vector, which can not be used for image feature (such as SIFT) extraction implementation. The following is my code:

```
conn = database.ODBCConnection('test','username','password'); 
curs = exec(conn,'select image from roomimage'); % image is the column of saved blob data, and roomimage is the table in database
curs = fetch(curs); 
img=curs.Data{1,1}; % as and example, read the first image
```

Then I get class(img)=unit8, size is 111365*1

Then if I write and save as image file:

```
imwrite(img,'test.jpg')
imwrite(img,'test.png') % alternatively, I also tried to save it as .png file
```

Here comes the problem: the saved file cannot be opened! :(

Could someone show me, when using MATLAB, how to read blob data from mysql, save it as .jpg file, which can be opened as an image? Thank you very much!!!

#

Add: if I export and save image from mysql beforehand, then load image from local file to MATLAB, I get something like:683*1024*3 unit8 data, which is NOT like the N*1 vector read from mysql...